# How to access CMS website running apache on Win7 through LAN

Tags: apache, windows-7, wamp, lan, easyphp

I am running a web server on a Windows 7 PC using EasyPHP (a portable local WAMP). That is my **computer_1** and has IP address of `10.0.1.6`.

Now I have another computer (**computer_2**) on the LAN with IP address `10.0.1.203`.

I want to access the sites on **computer_1** from **computer_2**.

When I type `10.0.1.6` in the web browser of **computer_2**, I can see the list of sites that are in `\WWW` folder of EasyPHP but I can't access the WordPress websites: I receive the error `unable to establish connection`.

I modified the Apache HTTP Server config for `ServerName 10.0.1.6:8888` and `Listen (same ip)`, `Allow from all`, then disabled firewall, opened port `8888` for incoming connections.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

It would be much easier to troubleshoot your case if you provide more details.

- What version of EasyPHP WAMP package do you have installed?
- What do you see on the logs?
- What's the **exact error wording** in a web browser?

EasyPHP provides pretty interface so you could easily manage the WAMP instance without manually editing the Apache (or other) config in common cases. I can assume that there is some simple misconfiguration which would be easy to solve after checking the logs. So since you can reach the server and get some error -- check the logs for clues on the root cause.